# Hugo doesn't show pages in a subdirectory [File.Dir]

Tags: html, go, hugo

When I add files into the main content directory everything works fine. The .md post files show up, but when I put my files into the subdirectories. The `{{ range (where .Pages "File.Dir" "in" "/articles/") }}` code just doesn't do anything. Nothing is showing up. I included part of my website's index.html file for a broader reference. I have an articles folder (/content/articles/) and inside there are multiple .md files. I am running Hugo on windows 10.

Thanks for your help

```
<div class="row" id="articles">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h3 class="category_header">Articles</h3>
            <div class="article_list card-body">
                    <ul>
                        {{ range (where .Pages "File.Dir" "in" "/articles/") }}
                        <li>
                            {{ .PublishDate.Format "Jan 2006" }} -
                            <a href="{{.Permalink}}">{{.Title}}</a>
                        </li>
                        {{ end }}
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit: I think this is related to windows paths. I re-created my website on Ubuntu and didn't have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I posted this question, I have switched to Ubuntu and my blog appear to be working fine and forgot this problem existed until I decided to use a windows machine again. Now I learned through a hugo support forum that the cause of this is File.Dir variable. Quoting the answer [in the hugo support forum:](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/posts-not-showing-in-windows-but-showing-in-ubuntu-hugo-server/27971) In UNIX File.Dir variable is producing  `/notebooks/` while in Windows it will produce `\notebooks\`

So replacing the

```
{{ range (where .Pages "File.Dir" "in" "/articles/") }}
```

to:

```
{{ range (where .Pages "File.Dir" "in" "\\articles\\") }}
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this on my windows 10 box.

But in general, you should probably be using

```
{{ range .Section "articles" }}
```

instead.